# Evaluating a comma separated Expression using DataTable.Compute in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable, asp.net-mvc-5, currentculture

I have an expression which contains numbers that are separated by `, or .`, i.e a number in the expression can be `2,3 or 2.3`. I get values to generate the expression from the database where the values are stored in one of the above format. I have an additional textbox in the `Calculate` page where the user enters a value during runtime.

If the value are in the format `2.3` the value  is computed by `DataTable.Compute` and the result is in the **comma separated format**. How do I make `DataTable.Compute` to evaluate any string?

I have added but still it doesn't work. I get `SyntaxErrorException`

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

EDIT

Replacing the `,` in the expression with `.` can solve the problem. But when the result is displayed in the comma separated format why doesn't it accept input in the same format?

Comment: are the numbers alone? i mean you can convert `,` to `.` if they are not inside expression so `,` as decimal seperator will not be confused with other things inside expression and you can safely change `,` to `.`

Comment: that was a real straightforward thing that i too thought of, to replace `,` with `.`. But I think there should be a way using this `CultureInfo` to evaluate the expression. I am not sure.

Comment: And the interesting part is that I get the result in the comma separated format. :)